# Go Multi Module Dependency Management

Tags: go, module, dependencies, multi-module, go-modules

I am new to goLang. I am tring to develop a multiModule project. my workspace folder is
like

```
root
   1-Authz
   1.1-Main.go
   1.2-go.mod (contains:module com.mbt.authz)
   1.3-go.sum
   2-Product
   2.1-Main.go
   2.2-go.mod  (contains:module com.mbt.product)
   2.3-go.sum
   3-go.work
   4-GoMultiModule.code-workspace

   go.work folder is like 
   go 1.18

   use(
    ./Authz
    ./Product
   )
```

Both modules can run by itself. But I want to define a method in Authz and call that
function from Product. What should I do, how can I add dependency to Product module from my local workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a FAQ for many new golang developer.

**In golang, Module and Package are not the same thing.** A module may contains one or more packages. Module is initialized with `go mod init [modulename]` command. This command will create a go.mod file. Package can be simply defined in code with `package [packagename]`. Package in the same module (let's call it local package) can be import with `import "[packagename] [modulename]/[pathofpackage]"`

In your case, if you don't want to create different module, you can delete the go.mod and go.sum file in both Authz and Products folder. Then in Root folder, run `go mod init root`. Then import auth package in product code with something like `import (authz "root/authz")` (authz is the package name delcared in Authz's code)

If authz has to be a different module, it will be treated as a different module which cannot be import diretly like a local package.

To import a local module in Authz folder, you need to edit the go.mod file in products folder like this:

```
module somemodulename

go 1.16

require (
    authzmodulename v0.0.0
)

replace authzmodulename v0.0.0 => ../Authz/
```

Answer (score 2):

For testing, simply add to `Product/main.go` an import referring to `Authz`:

```
import com/mbt/authz/aPackage
```

This assumes you define a method in a package different from `main`, in `Authz` project.